# Windwos azure mobile service - select multiple items with matching id

Tags: android, list, azure, cloud, where-clause

I'm having some troubles with Windows Azure mobile service. I'm writing an android application and using the mobile service jar.

Currently I'm using the folowing code to select objects with matching ids:

```
for(int i = 0; i < toBeFetched.size(); i++){

        final Sync curr = toBeFetched.get(i); 

        table.where().field("id").eq(toBeFetched.get(i).row_id).execute(new  TableQueryCallback<Inventory>() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List<Inventory> inventoryRows, int arg1, Exception e,
                    ServiceFilterResponse arg3) {

                if(e == null){
                    if(curr.action.equals("insert")){
                        insertInventoryRow.add(inventoryRows.get(0)); 
                    }else if(curr.action.equals("update")){
                        updateInventoryRow.add(inventoryRows.get(0)); 
                    }

                    DataRowFetched(); 
                }else{
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                }
            }
        }); 
    }
```

However, this creates a new socket on every item in the list so this doesen't scale very well. Is there a way of selecting an object with a matching id from a list of local objects?

Preferably i whould like to make just one call and get a list of inventory rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Scripts** to get the objects of selected ids. By sending a **parameter** with your **query**. This parameter will include the value of id you want to select, you can also send the toBeFetched.size() as a parameter and select the top results which you want.
This [link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-how-to-use-server-scripts/) can help you a lot

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm already doing some filering of the response with scripts but it's nothing too advanced, so I'm familiar with the concept. However, I have a hunch that you are mainly focusing on the API:s here or am I wrong? Or is this possible with the standard CRUD:s given by the portal (insert/update/delete/read)?